# AngularJS Dependency Injection Format

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angular, I dont understand why `$scope` and `$http` is placed before `function` these way

```
app.controller('PlayerController', ['$scope', '$http', 
  function($scope, $http) {
  var audio = document.createElement('audio');
  $scope.audio = audio;
  // ...
```

Why do it that way? 
Reading : http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/beginner2expert-services.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are placed so that code doesn't get broken when you minify it. You could do just

```
function($scope, $http) {
// use $scope
}
```

and Angular will know from parameter names that it needs to give you `$scope` and `$http` service. But when you minify the code, it could become something like this

```
function(a, b) {
// use a
}
```

where a is `$scope` and b is `$http` service. For that reason, AngularJS allows you to specify as string names of services you need injected. JavaScript minification doesn't modify strings, so

```
['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
}]
```

would become

```
['$scope', '$http', function(a, b) {
  // a is $scope
  // b is $http
}]
```

---

You should read more about [AngularJS dependency injection on Angular developer guide](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di). There are more ways to do injection. Following are equivalent:

```
// 1st way
app.controller('PlayerController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
}]);

// 2nd way
app.controller('PlayerController', function ($scope, $http) {
  // this will work if you don't minify your JavaScript
}]);

// 3rd way
function playerController($scope, $http) {
}
playerController['$inject'] = ['$scope', '$http'];
app.controller('PlayerController', playerController);
```

---

This is not something specific for controllers. Same thing (Dependency injection style) applies for services, factories etc.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand it is just for minification/uglifying the code.  If the parameters get changed then the app will fail.  That is all; nothing special.

Actually if you do not minification/uglifying your code and omit the strings in question it will work fine.